# How to properly select and filter data line in Python?

Tags: python-2.7, for-loop

How to remove unwanted line no. 8 from the result after filtering using below programme??. The actual result should not pick up whole line in month '10'.

```
month=('11','12','1','2','3')
newfile = open('result.xls', 'w')
with open('data.dat', 'r') as inF:
    for line in inF:
        if any(s in line[11] for s in month):
            data=line
            print data
            newfile.write("%s" % data)
    newfile.close()
```

Result:

```
96413   1981    11  2   7   0   0
96413   1982    11  3   8   200 0.3
96413   1983    12  4   9   180 0.8
96413   1983    1   5   10  100 1.5
96413   1984    1   7   11  80  2
96413   1985    2   8   12  80  1.5
96413   1986    3   5   13  190 0.9
96413   1986    10  4   14  200 0.5
```

Set of data.dat;

```
96413   1981    11  2   7   0   0
96413   1982    11  3   8   200 0.3
96413   1983    12  4   9   180 0.8
96413   1983    1   5   10  100 1.5
96413   1984    1   7   11  80  2
96413   1985    2   8   12  80  1.5
96413   1986    3   5   13  190 0.9
96413   1986    10  4   14  200 0.5
```

Thanks..

Comment: What do you think `line[11]` evaluates to?

Comment: i can say that it is the location value of month

Comment: Can you validate that assumption?  I suspect `line[11]` may not be what you think it is.

Comment: ohh really...yes will do that..tq